# Why my app doesn't deploy on shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny

I followed the same commands shown in [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/dashboard) for uploading my app but I get the following error:

```
> library(shinyapps)
> shinyapps::deployApp("/Users/mona/CS764/demo")
Error in lint(appDir) : Cancelling deployment: invalid project layout.
The project should have one of the following layouts:
1. 'shiny.R' and 'ui.R' in the application base directory,
2. 'shiny.R' and 'www/index.html' in the application base directory,
3. An R Markdown (.Rmd) document.
```

Here's the structure of my files:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `shinyapps::deployApp("/Users/mona/CS764/demo/1a")`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked but is giving me this error: `* Failed to parse /Users/mona/CS764/demo/vldb/ui.R.BACKUP.4098.R

Error in parse(input, n = -1L, encoding = checkEncoding(file)) : 
  63:1: unexpected input
62:         tabPanel("Result", selectInput("featureEx", "Feature Exploration",
63: << ^` you know how to fix it?

Comment: "Unexpected input" sounds it's probably like a typo in your code. Check for misplaced commas or parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `deployApp()` you must deploy the directory containing your `ui.R` and `server.R` files (or `shiny.R` / `www/index.html` if using a custom UI). The files can not be a subdirectory.

Additionally, its important to note that any R files in the directory or any subdirectory will be parsed, so its important that they have valid syntax.